# apply separate design to other elements in css

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a separate design to the home button i want to make the button as a complete block.I want to distinguish it between the other buttons like note 1 , note 2 , etc

```css
h1 {
  color: #0B1048;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ABD1D1;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #2A2F66;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #C7E5E5;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 10px;
  margin-block-end: 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Odibee Sans', cursive;
  background-image: url('img.pn');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 8;
}

section {
  color: turquoise;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  color: chocolate;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
}

div {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #2A2F66;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D9F1F1;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #C7E5E5;
  color: #2A2F66;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ABD1D1;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
}

#ad {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="top">MY DIARY</h1>
  <h2>INDEX</h2>
  <p id="ad"><a href="#note1">Note : 1</a>
    <a href="#note2">Note : 2</a>
    <a href="#note3">Note : 3</a>
    <a href="#note4">Note : 4</a>
    <a href="#note5">Note : 5</a><br>
    <a href="#note6">Note : 6</a>
    <a href="#note7">Note : 7</a>
    <a href="#note8">Note : 8</a>
    <a href="#note9">Note : 9</a>
    <a href="#note10">Note : 10</a><br>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </p>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lycke1s/

Comment: you should do it with different class rules to your a tags

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (and just css basics in general) as to how you can apply styles to specific elements. As an example, you can apply a class to an element like so:

```html
<a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
```

and then target it with the  class selector (`.`) like so:

```css
.home {
    /* Styles go here */
}
```